# 'int' object is not iterable error. What to do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`"int" object is not iterable.`

I have been trying hard to get rid of it.

```
a = [
    0,[(1,2,3),(1,2,3)],
    1,[(4,5,6),(4,5,6)],
    2,[(7,8,9),(7,8,9)]]
li = list() #list for storing list of tuples
i = 0 #key
d = dict((i,li) for i,li in a) #Error
print(d)
```

Comment: @khelwood maybe he wanted a dict instead of a list ?-)

Comment: Elements of `a` don't have two components each. For example, how does the first element of `a`, which is `0`, give values for `i` and `li`? Just because your formatting pairs up the `a` elements as you show doesn't make them paired. You need, `a = [ [0, [(1,2,3), (1,2,3)]], [1,[(4,5,6),(4,5,6)]],  [2,[(7,8,9),(7,8,9)]] ]`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You may well be correct.

Answer (score 0):

`for i, li in a` is equivalent to

```
for index in range(len(a)):
    i, li = a[index]
```

Now your list `a`'s first element is an int:

```
>>> print(a[0])
0
```

and you can't iterate over an int, obviously...